# Changing variable in a table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I make a changing variable an element of a table, like so.

```
local table = {}
local var = 10
```

Now I want to insert this variable as an element of `table`.
Something like this:

```
table[1] = var
```

What I need is, whenever I call this `table[1]`, even if the variable changes, it will call the actual value of that variable, like this:

```
print(table[1]) -> prints 10
var = var + 5
print(table[1]) -> prints 15
```

Is this even possible somehow?

EDIT:
What I want to accomplish is the following: I want to have an element in table that says which variable should be shown. For example:

```
local var1 = 10
local var2 = 20
```

Now if I have a table that has elements as strings of those variables like so:

```
local table = {"var1", "var2"}
```

Now if I do `print(table[1])`, of course it will print out "var1", but is there any way I could turn this element of a table that is `string` into a call for variable when I actually need that variable. You might be asking why don't I just call the `var1`, but there is a reason which I can explain, but it would be really long. Let's say I just need it this way. Also, the `var1`/`var2` **CAN CHANGE**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of choices.

1) Field function as a closure over var: Straightforward but requires changes how you use it

```
local t = {}
local var = 10
t.varf = function() return var end -- varf could be named var but that might be confusing

var = var + 5
print(t.varf()) -- call it to get the value
```

2) __index metamethod to avoid the explicit function call syntax

```
local t = {}
local var = 10
setmetatable(t, { 
    __index = function(_, k) 
        if k=="var" then return var else return nil 
    end})

var = var + 5
print(t.var) -- t does not contain a field with key "var" so __index is called
```

(The __index function is also a closure over var.)
If you want to modify var via t, then look to the [__newindex](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) metamethod.

Both methods use closures. A closure is a function that refers to non-global variables outside of its parameters and body.

Comment: I really like the 1) solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in Lua are shared by *copy*, at time of assignment. The `table[1]` and `var` both receive their own, independent copy of the number `10`.

If you want to share numbers, you'll need to encapsulate them in their own table.

```
local table = {}
local var = { value = 10 }

table[1] = var

print(table[1].value) -- prints 10
var.value = var.value + 5
print(table[1].value) -- prints 15
```

You can also consider creating some kind of abstraction over numbers. A quick example. You'll need to make sure your operations are well defined, though.

```
local number = {}
number.__index = number

local function Number (value)
    return setmetatable({ value = value }, number)
end

function number.__add (a, b)
    if type(b) == 'number' then
        return Number(a.value + b)
    elseif getmetatable(b) == number then
        return Number(a.value + b.value)
    end

    error("one of `number, Number' expected")
end

function number:add (n)
    if type(n) == 'number' then
        self.value = self.value + n
    elseif getmetatable(n) == number then
        self.value = self.value + n.value
    else
        error("one of `number, Number' expected")
    end

    return self.value
end

function number.__tostring (v)
    return v.value .. ''
end



local foo = {}
local bar = Number(10)
foo[1] = bar

print(foo[1]) -- 10
bar:add(5)
print(foo[1]) -- 15
print(bar + 25) -- 40
```

Comment: Even tho this helps, I want to ask something else.
Can I do something like this:

local var = 10
local table = {"var"}

Now, can I somehow turn this string to call the actually variable, or is that impossible?

Comment: @FICHEKK It'd be nice if we knew what you were trying to do exactly, because you're likely approaching the problem in the wrong way. It is possible to get local values via `debug` operations, but it's very inelegant.