# How do I change a pre-defined variable in a table in Luau?

Tags: lua, iterator, lua-table, luau

In a Roblox game I'm programming, I want to have a table of boolean values to iterate over ensuring that they're all `false` before making another one `true`, e.g.;

```lua
local bool1 = true
local bool2 = false
local bool3 = false
local bool4 = false
local tbl1 = {}

table.insert(tbl1,boolX) -- where "X" is the number above, did this in interest of shortening

for i,v in pairs(tbl1) do
  if v then v = not v end
end
```

However, as stated in the penultimate paragraph of section 2.1 of the 5.3 manual (knowing, albeit, that Luau uses 5.1 as its base);

> Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects: variables do not actually contain these values, only references to them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply any kind of copy.

That in mind, that means that I'm not *actually* shoving `bool1` through `bool4` into the table, just their values; the table would look like `{true, false, false, false}`. This means that I can't simply write a loop to iterate through the table and invert any `true`s I find;

```lua
local bool1 = true
local tbl1 = {}
table.insert(tbl1,bool1)
tbl1[1] = false
print(bool1)
print(tbl[1])

--output:
--  true
--  false
```

I should point out that I very well could just shove all my variables into one giant if/else and call it a night, but that is a *lot* of variables to check, a *lot* of typing, and I can't think of any other more elgant and less tedious way other than finding a form of iteration over them all.

I want to be able to have an actual reference, in some form, to the actual variables so that I can modify them from within the table and make them iterable.

- I've attempted to follow the examples given in the [best answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885500/10117098), with no successes. I would need to be able to, and cannot with these examples, substitute for any given variable at any given time, rather than just having one or two I want declated and thus returned as shown. I've attempted wrapping them in a function to provide my table and variable as arguments, but that doesn't seem to have any effect; it either outputs nothing, or `nil`.
- The [following answer after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884719/10117098) has one example that seems like it could work, but overall is pointless for what I'm trying to achieve; I don't want to re-declare or re-assign the variables I already have, I just want to return the specific value.
- I've attempted using a key/value pair, making the key the potential variable name and making it equal the variable's value, but I've no way to make that key return a variable of the same name. I even attempted merging this method and the `setmetatable` method mentioned in the first set of examples to see if I couldn't substitute from there, to no avail.

I should point out that, while I'm not a complete newbie to Lua or Luau, I'm also not an expert in the field by any meaning of the word; I'll catch on quick, but where possible, explain like I'm 10.

Comment: There are two ways I'm aware of right now: use a "pointer" e.g. yourBool = {true}, then shove that "pointer" into the array. Or you can use the index, e.g. shoving "yourBool" into the array, then indexing it using `_G[key]` (Assuming all variables are global and in _G). But I recommend rethinking the whole data structure here. Why dont you use the array, or better, a table right away? E.g. `yourBools = {bool1 = true, bool2 = false}` for both storing and indexing the booleans?

Comment: I agree with Luke, you're better off going the key-value route and referring to the table, not the variables

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunately looking like it's gonna be the call. I was initially trying not to go for placing them in a table right away, because the initial codebase for the game (I'm just another dev) just defined them as it was needed and that means a lot of refactoring, but if there's no true way to just refer to variables (easily and "natively" at least), then that might be my route. I'm probably gonna leave this question up for a bit longer for any other options someone may have, but otherwise I might just add that as "my own" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There is no way to do this in Roblox Luau.

Any potential way to do so in standard Lua is impossible to do in Luau due to how heavily sandboxed the latter is compared to the former.

Possible solutions that were recommended via comments include: making the variables needed available in `_G` as globals, then using them there; or using a pointer value in the table equivalent to the one you want, even though it won't technically change the value you want itself.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691964/10117098) recommends the use of `debug.getlocal()` for standard Lua, but doesn't work in Luau; keep this in mind when attempting to use it, as you *will* get an `attempt to call a nil value` error.

#### The recommended way to do this is not to do it at all, and instead have your variables and/or values in your table from the start.

Not only does this provide ease-of-access in many cases, but it will allow you to iterate through them significantly easier than trying to shove them into tables and the like. Refactoring, if you need to do something similar to this, is highly recommended across the board.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to iterate over local variables that are not referenced by table fields, is to use [debug.getlocal](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getlocal) in a loop.

Opinionated:

But this is a very bad approach to your problem.

You should refactor the code. If you need to update a list of variables have them in a list from the start. Don't be afraid of refactoring. Improving things usually pays off on the long term.

If your codebase is so bad that you are afraid of putting a few variables into a table you should really think over the design.

Comment: Unfortunately, `getlocal` was removed in Luau, so while this might work in standard Lua, it won't work for my use case. I've gone ahead and refactored since there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I needed in Luau.